# how to get the text from a hidden td of a multi row table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi row table
e.g

```
<table id="datable_1">
<tr>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td>lorem ipsum</td>
   <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please take note: This is a multirow table that keeps on increasing its row based from data. I DON'T USE ID nor CLASSES in any of the `<tr>` or `<td>` tag

Please help me to get the value of hidden td from each row.

here's my starting code

```
let elems = $('#datable_1 tr');
$(elems).each(function(index) {
  if (index !== 0) {
    console.log(elem.eq(8).text());
  }
});
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the `#datable_1` ID?

Comment: It's always the last `td` hence... [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) it

Comment: I already put the datable_1 ID ..modified my example

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the *tr* element, then find the specific *td* element from the current element.

```
$('#datable_1 tr').each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).find('td:eq(8)').text());
});
```

```js
$('#datable_1 tr').each(function(index) {
   console.log($(this).find('td:eq(8)').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datable_1">
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**OR:** With `nth-child`:

```
$('#datable_1 tr td:nth-child(9)').each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$('#datable_1 tr td:nth-child(9)').each(function(index) {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datable_1">
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If the targeted element is always the last child then it is better to use `:last-child` selector:

```
$('#datable_1 tr td:last-child').each(function(index) {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```js
$('#datable_1 tr td:last-child').each(function(index) {
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="datable_1">
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td>lorem ipsum</td>
     <td style="display:none;">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Andreas, as OP attempted his code with `:eq()`, I thought there could be other *td*s after :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any hidden `<td>` text, not only the last one in each `<tr>`, you can iterate each `<td>` directly checking if it has `display: none`.

```
let elems = $('#datable_1 td');
$(elems).each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).css('display') === "none") {
    console.log($(this).text())
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be making use of classes.

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

<td class="hidden">I WANT TO GET THIS HIDDEN TEXT</td>
```

Then, in jQuery, you can iterate over `$(".hidden")` and get text using `$(this).text()`.

If not, then do this:

```
let elems = $('#datable_1 td');

//iterating over all "tds"
$(elems).each(function() {
  if ($(this).css('display') == "none") {
          console.log($(this).text()));
      }
});
```